# Filtering normalized data structure

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, normalizr

Forgive me, I'm new to normalizr+redux. I've managed to normalize my data and create a reducer and end up with :

```
state = {
    installations:{
        "1":{...},
        "2":{...}
    }
}
```

I would then like to filter this data for use in a UI component into two separate categories (in this case where the installation.operator is equal to the current user). I've managed an implementation that works however it seems exhaustive:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    console.log("mapStateToProps", state.installations);
    let assignedInstallations = Object.keys(state.installations)
        .filter(i => {
            return state.installations[i].operator == state.login;
        })
        .map(i => {
            return state.installations[i];
        });
    let unassignedInstallations = Object.keys(state.installations)
        .filter(i => {
            return state.installations[i].operator != state.login;
        })
        .map(i => {
            return state.installations[i];
        });
    return {
        assignedInstallations,
        unassignedInstallations,
        loginUserId: state.login
    };
};
```

I'm also new to ES6 and am not across all the new syntax shortcuts etc so I suspect there are much better ways to do this.

Is there a more succinct approach with a similar outcome?

Comment: i kind of feel like i want to de-normalize and just use `filter`, but then why did i normalize ... ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with only one `reduce()`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    console.log("mapStateToProps", state.installations);
    let {assignedInstallations, 
         unassignedInstallations } = Object.keys(state.installations)
          .reduce(function(acc, cur, i){
             if(state.installations[i].operator == state.login){
               acc.assignedInstallations.push(state.installations[i]);
             }else{
               acc.unassignedInstallations .push(state.installations[i]);
             }
             return acc
           }, {assignedInstallations: [], unassignedInstallations: [] })

    return {
        assignedInstallations,
        unassignedInstallations,
        loginUserId: state.login
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`lodash` (An utility library) have a notion of collection (Here is an example https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter for `filter` function). It takes as input Object or Array and returns an Array. It seems to fit to your needs. Here is the refactored code:

```
import {
  filter,
} from 'lodash'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    let assignedInstallations = filter(state.installations, installation => installation.operator == state.login);
    let unassignedInstallations = filter(state.installations, installation => installation.operator != state.login);
    return {
        assignedInstallations,
        unassignedInstallations,
        loginUserId: state.login
    };
};
```